# How to stomp keep alive in PHP?

Tags: php, stomp

Always wait for the read timeout before reconnecting.

How to keep alive `Connection` or reusable `Client`?

```php
try {
    $next = true;

    do {
        $connection = new Connection($brokerUrl, 1);

        $client = new Client($connection);
        $client->setLogin($userName, $passcode);
        $client->setClientId($queueName);
        $client->setHeartbeat(2, 2);
        $client->connect();
        echo 'connected' . PHP_EOL;

        $stomp = new SimpleStomp($client);
        $stomp->subscribe($queueName, 2);

        do {
            echo 'reading' . PHP_EOL;

            $msg = $stomp->read();

            var_dump($msg);

            if (false === $msg) {
                echo 'timeout' . PHP_EOL;
                unset($stomp);
                $client->disconnect();
                unset($client);
                break;
            }

            print_r($msg->body);

            sleep(1);

        } while(true);

        echo 'closed' . PHP_EOL;
        
        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/stop')) {
            $next = false;
        }
    } while($next);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r($ex);
}
```

I want to remove the block.

```php
            if (false === $msg) {
                echo 'timeout' . PHP_EOL;
                unset($stomp);
                $client->disconnect();
                unset($client);
                break;
            }
```

The `$stomp` can still read. Actually, when `$stomp` timeout, it does not work.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please elaborate on the problem you're facing and what you've done in an attempt to resolve it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).